# Maximum size of $k$-wise linearly independent set within $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, ..., u \rbrace^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, co.combinatorics

Given a positive integer $u$, how many $k$-dimensional vectors whose coordinates are all in $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, ..., u\rbrace$ can you choose so that any $k$ of them are linearly independent? Equivalently, what is the size of the largest subset of $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, ... u \rbrace^k$ so that each hyperplane through the origin contains at most $k-1$ of them?

If $k=2$, two vectors are linearly dependent iff they have the same slope, so the maximum number of pairwise independent vectors is the number of distinct slopes $y/x$ with $1\le x,y \le u$,

$$ -1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^u \phi(n),$$

since the number of slopes up to $1$ with reduced denominator $n$ is $\phi(n)$, and slopes other than $1$ come in reciprocal pairs.

Comment: Hei, this site is for research-level questions, so this question is not appropriate here.  See http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot for some places where your question will be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I rewrote the main question so that it does sound research level, at least at the moment, at least to my ears. (Is it easy and I don't see it, MTS?) I couldn't make sense of the "sub problem" so I deleted that part for now.

Comment: David, thank you. Before I submitted the question, I read through http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask. I just wanted to make this question very clear, specific and precise. Actually, my original question is an optimization problem as you stated with many constraints.  

Comment: Which asymptotic region are you interested in?

Comment: I misread David Feldman's rewrite, mistaking a "dependent" for "independent," so my rewrite may have been redundant.

Comment: Douglas, thank you very much. Your edit is close to my original problem and main applications. When k=2, I've already got its bound. Also, in my published paper on ICC 2012 (you can see it in my website, page 5), I gave a loose bound for one transform of this problem. Also before I submitted this question, I discussed it with many classmates and several famous guys such as Beigel, Richard, Richard Karp and Adi Shamir. I got to know this website yesterday and decided to post this question. And I will learn how to write my problem and paper in research level since I am not a student in Math.    

Comment: Gjergji, right now I haven't decided to work on one specific asymptotic region since my current main research topic is computer science.  

Comment: I can only guess that MTS saw the linear algebra tag and mistook your question for a textbook exercise.  I rewrote it to protect it from getting closed before it attracted attention.  Success! 

Asymptotically, Douglas' quantity grows as $u^2/\zeta(2)$ and this generalizes to $k>2$.


Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.  Withdrawing my vote to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tony already mentioned that the maximum size of a set of vectors that are $k$-wise linearly independent over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$ grows linearly with $q$.

In our situation, however, this is no longer true, and the right order of asymptotics is $O(u^{k/(k-1)})$. That is, if you keep $k$ fixed, the maximum number of $k$-wise linearly independent vectors from $\lbrace 1,2,\dots, u\rbrace ^k$ is $\sim u^{k/(k-1)}$. One has the same order of magnitude for the minimal number of linear subspaces needed to cover the points $\lbrace 1,2,\dots, u\rbrace ^k$. These statements are proved in

> I. Barany, G. Harcos, J. Pach and G. Tardos, "Covering Lattice Points by Subspaces",
>   Per. Math. Hung. 43, 2001, 93-103.

[Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.NT/0102030) is the arxiv link. I think that the right order of magnitude for the maximum number of such $k$-dimensional vectors so that any $r$ are linearly independent is not known for $r < k$. See [this artcle](http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/informatik/ThIS/downloads/publications/lefmann_no_three_submitted.pdf) for references on such generalizations.

Comment: I am traveling. Thank everyone here. After my traveling, I will update my ideas and goals.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but you may also be interested in the 'finite field' analogue of your question.  Namely, given a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, what is the maximum size of a subset of vectors $S \subset \mathbb{F}_q^k$ so that every subset of $S$ of size $k$ is linearly independent.

An old conjecture of Segre asserts that the maximum size of such a set is at most $q+1$, (except for some exceptional cases).  This [paper](http://www-ma4.upc.es/~simeon/jems-mds-conj-revised.pdf) of Ball proves the conjecture for $q$ prime (and some other cases).  He also proves that the largest examples are all essentially equivalent to the following example:

$$S:=\{(1,t, t^2, \dots, t^{k-1}) : t \in \mathbb{F}_q \} \cup \{(0, \dots, 0, 1)\}$$